# List methods on object

Tags: r

Using this code I extend summary to just return coefficient from a summary :

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(1,2,3)

m = lm(y ~ x)

tosum2 <- summary(m)
summary.myclass <- function(x)
{
  return(x$coef)
}
class(tosum2) <- c('myclass', 'summary')
summary(tosum2)
```

This returns :

```
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)        0          0     NaN      NaN
x                  1          0     Inf        0
```

There are methods within summary I wish to access such as Residuals but how to discover these method names ? 
In other words how to extend `summary.myclass` to return other data such as Residuals from existing summary ?

Comment: Have you checked the `broom` package? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/broom/versions/0.4.2

Comment: As an example try this: `library(broom);

m = lm(disp~hp, data = mtcars);

tidy(m);
augment(m)`

Comment: @blue-sky You can see all the class functions `methods(class = "yourclass")`. or you can use `getAnywhere(summary.yourclass)` to see the summary function